# How to debug dynamically-loaded scripts in VSCode for Chrome debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, chrome-debugging

It is impossible to set a breakpoint in a dynamically-loaded script in VSCode.

They turn out to be unverified breakpoints.

> Unverified breakpoint, Breakpoint ignored because generated code not
>   found (source map problem?).

I tried various sourceMap options in the launch.json - for no avail.

Comment: I have problem with dynamically loaded scripts as they have no extension so language is unknown and related features disabled. I have to manually set language to enable them.

Answer (score -1):

I lately started putting `debugger` where I want the code to stop for debugging.